# Nebula and its Colours

Tags: cosmology, nebula, observatory

A Nebula boasts of Too Bright Awesome Colors that includes red, blue, green, orange, white, etc?

They're result of excitation of electrons.

Is there a clear explanation as in which Color is attributed to an atom for Color properties in Cosmos!?

Comment: Can you make it clearer?